# Im trying to solve a normal query which chooses between three types of triangles based on the database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, switch-statement, case

Getting error where it says the syntax error before `=`

```
select t_name, 
case 
    when a=b then 'Isoscels' 
    when a=b=c then 'Equilateral'  
    when a<>b<>c then 'Scalene'  
    when (a+b)<c then 'Not A Triangle' 
end as t_name 
from triangles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this is the logic you intended:

```
SELECT
    t_name,
    CASE WHEN a = b THEN 'Isoscels'
         WHEN a = b AND b = c AND a = c THEN 'Equilateral'
         WHEN a <> b AND b <> c AND a <> c THEN 'Scalene'
         ELSE 'Not A Triangle' END AS t_name
FROM triangles;
```

As far as I know, it is not possible to chain equality expressions in SQL Server, as you might be able to do in other languages (e.g. JavaScript or maybe PHP).

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much for the explanation. I have started to learn SQL server hope this helps. Is there any blog that explains SQL server much more detailed?

Comment: @PaviThran Yes, there are many blogs about SQL Server.  You might also want to try participating in SQL Server questions on Stack Overflow, from which you would learn a lot.

Comment: yeah sure and looking forward to it. Now also working my rank up in hacker rank and improving my SQL knowledge.